# A perl script that worked on Snow Leopard No Longer Works On Lion

Tags: regex, perl, greedy

I used to take a arbitrary set of files on my Desktop in the format of:

> Screen Shot 2011-11-08 at 8.10.23 AM.png
>
> Screen Shot 2011-11-08 at 8.08.57 AM.png

run a Perl script on them and rename them to

> SS-2011-11-08 at 8.10.23 AM.png
>
> SS-2011-11-08 at 8.08.57 AM.png

This stopped working and no rename happens.  Now that I have to change it, I would like it to change to:

> ss-2011.11.08.at.8.10.23.AM.png
>
> ss-2011.11.08.at.8.08.57.AM.png

- replace "Screen Shot" as that exact case always to "ss"
- replace all `-` to `.`
- replace all spaces to `.`

I know it has to do with greediness, but I didn't write this and no matter how much fiddling I do I can't seem to get it to work.  I have used perl all of a few hours in my life. I think I could do this in php in a few lines, but would like to learn how to keep it in perl because it's always good to be able to debug.  I have looked up the regs formatting rules and they are not applying.  Either something is screwy in Mac OS X Lion, or Snow Leopard was allowing things to happen that shouldn't.

Thank you all!

Here is what I have so far:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

 chdir( "/Users/me/Desktop" ) or die;
 my @files = ();
 print "after my \@files array\n";
 print @files;

 while ( <*> ) {
    push @files, $_ if m!^Screen Shot (.*) at (.*)\.png!;
 }


 foreach my $f ( @files ) {
    my $new = $f;
    $new =~ s!^SS (.*) at (.*)\.png!ss-$1\_$2.png!;
    print "$f -> $new\n";
    rename ( $f, $new ) or die;
 }
```

Comment: Use the debugger (`perl -d ...`) and step through your code to find the problem.

Comment: Are there any error messages?  Can you give us some sample input?  Given the sample input, what was the actual output, and what was the expected output?

Comment: Write modern Perl, `use strict`!

Comment: And `use warnings`.  Think of the children!

Comment: @Jack Maney — Good point (although warnings are turned on, they are done so globally with `-w`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the replacement to this

```
$new =~ s/Screen\.Shot\.(.*)\.at\.(.*)/ss-$1.at.$2/;
```

and add another replacements *before* it:

```
$new =~ s/[- ]/./g;  # Replace all dashes and spaces to dots
```

Comment: This worked perfect. though in Lion the screen shot is no longer Screen shot but Screen Shot where the second word is caps on the "S".

Answer (score 0):

While you are adding all files to the array which match to the below regex :

```
/^Screen Shot (.*) at (.*)\.png/
```

You then try to replace every file from the aforementioned array which looks like :

```
/^SS (.*) at (.*)\.png/
```

How can you possibly expect this to work?

Answer (score 0):

First Expression (in the `if`)

```
m!^Screen Shot \d+-\d+-\d+ at \d+\.\d+\.\d+\s[AP]M\.png$!
```

Second Expression (though I would think technically redundant, because the match expression is the same except for the capturing groups) would be:

```
s!^Screen Shot (\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) at (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\s([AP]M)\.png$!ss-$1.$2.$3.at.$4.$5.$6.$7.png!
```

works for me, at least!

If you would like me to break it down for you, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Snow Leopard and my screen shots are saved as `Screen shot ...` (note the lowercase `s` on `shot`).  Does Lion now uses an uppercase `S`?  If so, and your original script used a lowercase `s`, then that was probably what broke it.  Either way, let's fix it.

Your substitution

```
$new =~ s!^SS (.*) at (.*)\.png!ss-$1\_$2.png!;
```

is looking for file names starting with `SS`, followed by a space, but it sounds like you want to change filenames starting with `SS` followed by a `-`, *or* `Screen [Ss]hot` followed by a space.

Also, as @FailedDev pointed out, your `while` loop is only adding files that match `^Screen Shot (.*) at (.*)\.png` to your `@files` array, so you're `foreach` loop never sees the files starting with `SS`.

Replace your code with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; # ALWAYS!

chdir( "/Users/me/Desktop" ) or die("Could not chdir() to ~/Desktop: $!");
foreach my $f (<*>) {
    my $new = $f;
    if ($new =~ s!^(?:SS-|Screen [Ss]hot )([\d-]+) at ([\d\.]+) ([AP]M)\.png!ss-$1.at.$2.$3.png!) {
        $new =~ s/\-/\./g;
        print "$f -> $new\n";
        rename ( $f, $new ) or die("Could not rename $f to $new: $!");
    }
}
```

To help you understand what's happening:

- The `^` after `s!` means look only at the beginning of the text to replace, in this case the file name
- The `|` between `SS-` and `Screen [Ss]hot` [grouped by `(?:)`] means look for either `SS-` or `Screen [Ss]hot`.
- The three capture groups [ surrounded by `()` *without* the `?:` ] do not contain spaces, so `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` in your replacement will not contain spaces.
- The `if` statement ensures that the code inside the `if` block only executes if the file name matches and the substitution actually takes place.